# How to encode text to base64 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, base64

I am trying to encode a text string to base64.

i tried doing this :

```
name = "your name"
print('encoding %s in base64 yields = %s\n'%(name,name.encode('base64','strict')))
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
LookupError: 'base64' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs
```

How do I go about doing this ? ( using Python 3.4)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60531872/13944524) answer.  base64 is **binary-to-text** encoding I don't know why python's base64 module doesn't convert it back to string by itself... [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Remember to import `base64` and that the `b64encode` function takes bytes as an argument.

```
import base64
b = base64.b64encode(bytes('your_string', 'utf-8')) # bytes
base64_str = b.decode('utf-8') # convert bytes to string
```

**Explanation:**

The `bytes` function creates a bytes object from the string *"your_string"* using [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding. In Python, `bytes` represents a sequence of bits and UTF-8 specifies the character encoding to use.

The `base64.b64encode` function encodes bytes object into Base64 format. It takes a bytes-like object as input and returns a Base64 encoded bytes object.

The `b.decode` function decodes the bytes object (here `b`) using UTF-8 encoding and returns the resulting string. It converts the bytes back to their original string representation.

Comment: how do i remove the leading b when printing this?

Comment: You need to decode it from bytes into a string using some encoding -- e.g. ascii or utf8.  (`b'home'.decode('ascii')` for example)

Comment: TypeError: encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'

Answer (score 36):

For `py3`, base64 `encode` and `decode` string:

```
import base64

def b64e(s):
    return base64.b64encode(s.encode()).decode()


def b64d(s):
    return base64.b64decode(s).decode()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer ! base64 is **binary-to-text encoding** I don't know why python's `base64` module doesn't convert it back to string by itself...

Comment: Exactly. And why `.b64decode` expects a string and not bytes. Why aren't the functions symmetrical?

Comment: It may be helpful to add encodings for your particular application. E.g. `return base64.b64encode(s.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'`).

Answer (score 31):

It turns out that this is important enough to get [it's own module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html)...

```
import base64
base64.b64encode(b'your name')  # b'eW91ciBuYW1l'
base64.b64encode('your name'.encode('ascii'))  # b'eW91ciBuYW1l'
```

Comment: gives me this error : `import base64
>>> base64.b64encode(b'%s'%name)
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement`

Comment: the `>>>` was copied from my terminal prompt.  Leave those out.

Comment: i did ... Those are from my terminal prompt

Comment: How do i remove the leading b during print out

Comment: @sukhvir -- check my response on the other answer ;-)

Comment: I suppose that syntax error is yet another IDLE 'feature'. It should support pasting multiple statements in the shell.

Comment: What about decoding the string afterwards?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro -- `base64.b64decode` or one of the [variants](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/base64.html#base64.standard_b64decode) depending on the alphabet used to encode ...

Answer (score 17):

1) This works without imports in Python 2:

```
>>>
>>> 'Some text'.encode('base64')
'U29tZSB0ZXh0\n'
>>>
>>> 'U29tZSB0ZXh0\n'.decode('base64')
'Some text'
>>>
>>> 'U29tZSB0ZXh0'.decode('base64')
'Some text'
>>>
```

(although this doesn't work in Python3 )

2) In Python 3 you'd have to import base64 and do base64.b64decode('...')
- will work in Python 2 too.

Comment: Be careful with this one! It adds newlines `\n` into the output about every 58 character.
`>>> 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.encode('base64')
'eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4\neHh4\n'`

Comment: per BASE64 Standard https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-3.3 newline characters must be ignored: "Note that this means that any adjacent carriage return/line feed (CRLF) characters constitute "non-alphabet characters" and are ignored." Also the new line characters are defined in the Standard as well https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-3.1 "As such, MIME enforces a limit on line length of base 64-encoded data to 76 characters"

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's essential to call the `decode()` function to make use of actual string data even after calling `base64.b64decode` over the `base64` encoded string. Because never forget, it always returns bytes literals.

```
import base64
conv_bytes = bytes('your string', 'utf-8')
print(conv_bytes)                                 # b'your string'
encoded_str = base64.b64encode(conv_bytes)
print(encoded_str)                                # b'eW91ciBzdHJpbmc='
print(base64.b64decode(encoded_str))              # b'your string'
print(base64.b64decode(encoded_str).decode())     # your string
```

Answer (score 4):

To compatibility with both py2 and py3

```
import six
import base64

def b64encode(source):
    if six.PY3:
        source = source.encode('utf-8')
    content = base64.b64encode(source).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Using this with GCP Deployment manager to base64 encode secrets.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you can of course use the `base64` module, you can also to use the `codecs` module (referred to in your error message)  for binary encodings (meaning non-standard & non-text encodings).

For example:

```py
import codecs
my_bytes = b"Hello World!"
codecs.encode(my_bytes, "base64")
codecs.encode(my_bytes, "hex")
codecs.encode(my_bytes, "zip")
codecs.encode(my_bytes, "bz2")
```

This can come in useful for large data as you can chain them to get compressed and json-serializable values:

```py
my_large_bytes = my_bytes * 10000
codecs.decode(
    codecs.encode(
        codecs.encode(
            my_large_bytes,
            "zip"
        ),
        "base64"),
    "utf8"
)
```

Refs:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#binary-transforms
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
import base64

#Taking input through the terminal.
welcomeInput= raw_input("Enter 1 to convert String to Base64, 2 to convert Base64 to String: ") 

if(int(welcomeInput)==1 or int(welcomeInput)==2):
    #Code to Convert String to Base 64.
    if int(welcomeInput)==1:
        inputString= raw_input("Enter the String to be converted to Base64:") 
        base64Value = base64.b64encode(inputString.encode())
        print "Base64 Value = " + base64Value
    #Code to Convert Base 64 to String.
    elif int(welcomeInput)==2:
        inputString= raw_input("Enter the Base64 value to be converted to String:") 
        stringValue = base64.b64decode(inputString).decode('utf-8')
        print "Base64 Value = " + stringValue

else:
    print "Please enter a valid value."
```

Comment: Please consider to translate your into Python 3 executable, since original post assumed it.

Comment: There are some older answers to this question. Can you comment what makes your's better?

Comment: @NicoHaase .. This code i had developed which can convert a string from String to Base64 and vice versa. You can directly run it as a python script.

Comment: That does not really answer my question: the OP is not asking for a script that makes everything possible, but for the purest call of converting a string to base64

Comment: @NicoHaase I was looking for solution to this question myself but the solutions provided were not enough for me. I saw the code somewhere else and then i wrote the whole solution at one place.

Answer (score 0):

> **Base64** encoding is a process of converting binary data to an ASCII
> string format by converting that binary data into a **6-bit character**
> representation. The **Base64** method of encoding is used when binary
> data, such as images or video, is transmitted over systems that are
> designed to transmit data in a **plain-text** (ASCII) format.

Follow this [link](https://www.lifewire.com/base64-encoding-overview-1166412) for further details about understanding and working of `base64` encoding.

For those who want to implement `base64` encoding from scratch for the sake of understanding, here's the code that encodes the string to `base64`.

## encoder.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

class Base64Encoder:

    #base64Encoding maps integer to the encoded text since its a list here the index act as the key
    base64Encoding:list = None

    #data must be type of str or bytes
    def encode(data)->str:
        #data = data.encode("UTF-8")

        if not isinstance(data, str) and not isinstance(data, bytes):
            raise AttributeError(f"Expected {type('')} or {type(b'')} but found {type(data)}")

        if isinstance(data, str):
            data = data.encode("ascii")

        if Base64Encoder.base64Encoding == None:
            #construction base64Encoding
            Base64Encoder.base64Encoding = list()
            #mapping A-Z
            for key in range(0, 26):
                Base64Encoder.base64Encoding.append(chr(key + 65))
            #mapping a-z
            for key in range(0, 26):
                Base64Encoder.base64Encoding.append(chr(key + 97))
            #mapping 0-9
            for key in range(0, 10):
                Base64Encoder.base64Encoding.append(chr(key + 48))
            #mapping +
            Base64Encoder.base64Encoding.append('+')
            #mapping /
            Base64Encoder.base64Encoding.append('/')


        if len(data) == 0:
            return ""
        length=len(data)

        bytes_to_append = -(length%3)+(3 if length%3 != 0 else 0)
        #print(f"{bytes_to_append=}")
        binary_list = []
        for s in data:
            ascii_value = s
            binary = f"{ascii_value:08b}" 
            #binary = bin(ascii_value)[2:]
            #print(s, binary, type(binary))
            for bit in binary:
                binary_list.append(bit)
        length=len(binary_list)
        bits_to_append = -(length%6) + (6 if length%6 != 0 else 0)
        binary_list.extend([0]*bits_to_append)

        #print(f"{binary_list=}")

        base64 = []

        value = 0
        for index, bit in enumerate(reversed(binary_list)):
            #print (f"{bit=}")
            #converting block of 6 bits to integer value 
            value += ( 2**(index%6) if bit=='1' else 0)
            #print(f"{value=}")
            #print(bit, end = '')
            if (index+1)%6 == 0:
                base64.append(Base64Encoder.base64Encoding[value])
                #print(' ', end="")

                #resetting value
                value = 0
                pass
        #print()

        #padding if there is less bytes and returning the result
        return ''.join(reversed(base64))+''.join(['=']*bytes_to_append)
```

## testEncoder.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

from encoder import Base64Encoder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Base64Encoder.encode("Hello"))
    print(Base64Encoder.encode("1 2 10 13 -7"))
    print(Base64Encoder.encode("A"))

    with open("image.jpg", "rb") as file_data:
        print(Base64Encoder.encode(file_data.read()))
```

## Output:

```
$ ./testEncoder.py 
SGVsbG8=
MSAyIDEwIDEzIC03
QQ==
```