# Decoding a dict of base64 strings gives error

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, base64

I am trying to decode a dict of base64 strings like this:

```
responses64 = {
'54sdf61': 'eyJyZXNwb2...', 
'23423vse': 'sdfwerfwewe...'
}
```

The data comes like this from an API query, so I can't change that part.

Normally, I'd do this to decode base64:

```
response = json.loads(base64.b64decode(response64))
```

But since I have adict now with many of these strings, I have go another way. The best I could come up with was a for-loop over the key values, which are stored in another list called `IDs`, and write the results into a dict:

```
responses = {}

for i in IDs:
    responses[i] = json.loads(base64.b64decode(responses64[i]))
```

However, this doesn't work, since b64decode doesn't like to operate on dicts:

`TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'dict'`

Any idea would be appreciated...

Comment: Umm... does `responses64.update((k, base64.b64decode(v)) for k, v in responses64.items())` do what you're after?

Comment: Funny enough, this works as it gives me strings of dicts. However, when I try to convert those dicts with `json.loads()`, I get `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: Pass a suitable `encoding=` to `json.loads()` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It seems like the API gives out some non-base64 encoded message when the string is empty, so I have to figure out a way to filter out these query results before decoding.

Comment: OK, so I ended up using `if not ... == '{'`: to filter out responses that returned an error message. Not very elegant, but it does the trick, since all valid responses will be base64 encoded and thus not start with a `{`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [json Encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

so either using with `base64`

```
responses[i] = json.loads(base64.b64decode(json.dumps(responses64[i])))
```

or

```
response = json.loads(json.dumps(responses64))
```

Comment: Hmm... this doesn't decode anything unfortunately. It just seems to put the base64 code into a string. Do you mean I should use this within the decode function? Because that results in the same error.

Comment: Yup , 

try that `response = json.loads(json.dumps(responses64))`

Comment: This also works up until the part where I want to loop over `json.loads()` again. The decoding seems to work, but json.loads doesn't seem to like my loop: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: json.loads dosen't need a loop

Comment: I have a dictionary of strings, resulting from your loop. Each string is another dictionary. It doesn't get flattened automatically, so I have to loop over these strings again in order to get my desired results, no?

Comment: check that 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508726/how-to-encode-python-dictionary