# read XML with binary content

Tags: python, xml

I would like to use Python to read a VTU file which is XML and may raw contain binary data. [The specification](https://vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf) says:

> There is one case in which the file is not a valid XML document. When the AppendedData section is not encoded as base64,
>   raw binary data is present that may violate the XML specification. This is not default behavior, and must be explicitly enabled
>   by the user.

For example, check [`dragon.vtu`](https://github.com/topology-tool-kit/ttk-data/blob/master/dragon.vtu):

```xml
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="1.0" byte_order="LittleEndian" header_type="UInt64">
  <UnstructuredGrid>
    <Piece NumberOfPoints="69827" NumberOfCells="139650">
      <Cells>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="connectivity" format="appended" RangeMin="" RangeMax="" offset="837932"/>
        <DataArray type="Int64" Name="offsets" format="appended" RangeMin="" RangeMax="" offset="4189540"/>
        <DataArray type="UInt8" Name="types" format="appended" RangeMin="" RangeMax="" offset="5306748"/>
      </Cells>
    </Piece>
  </UnstructuredGrid>
  <AppendedData encoding="raw">
   _$É�����Ä±AdÌAÁÊÃÿ@>yAn£GÁÏAA(~AÁþ`AF¶Áo.@Ô«¬A3Ä|Ásc2@ï8±A cÁÉX@®AZ/AÏ±Á:»AA)³Á(ÉAs!AFÁ\A½A*ÁyA*)AéÔÁØÓAÀ¡Aã_ÁóA`öBÌ]gADé¸AdBdÌnA|r·AhB^ºnA­zºAÈÂ¦
   [...]
```

Naively doing

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
parser = ET.XMLParser()
tree = ET.parse("dragon.vtu", parser)
```

does *not* work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 3, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse("dragon.vtu", parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1197, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 604, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 28, column 5
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your data is not XML due to consisting of illegal characters, therefore any conformant XML parser will properly reject it.

Fix the problem upstream: Rather than embedding binary data directly, first encoded as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

**See also**

- [XML Schema. Base64binary type vs String type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34411824/290085)
- [How to encode text to base64 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23164058/290085)

---

***I cannot fix the problem upstream...***

Then you're in the unfortunate position of having received data that is not XML.  See the following for your options: [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

***...since the binary content is part of the VTU specification.***

Any specification that includes unconstrained binary data in XML is broken as designed.  Your options include those of parsing bad XML (see above link), using only the culprit's provided libraries/toolkits, or writing your own library/toolkit – not great options, but such are the consequences of vendors not following the XML specification.

Comment: I cannot fix the problem upstream since the binary content is part of the VTU specification. I've added a link to the original question.

Comment: Specifications are nice. Then reality is different.

Comment: @Gzorg: Followed specifications are even nicer.  Reality may be that mistakes are made.  Mistakes should be corrected at the source.  If not possible, see [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)